# Setting the Request Header

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

I'm sending the request with header as.

```
  NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                               @"Connection":@"keep-alive",
                               @"cache-control": @"no-cache",
                               @"postman-token": @"eb834958-a82f-3fd8-0b64-e007df45835c" };

    NSMutableData *postData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[@""   dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *logString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Here the Url is : \n\n\n\n %@ \n\n\n\n\nAction Used is :========>  %@ \n\n\n\n\n and the Parmeter posted are :=============> %@",IOS_BASE_URL,action,parmetersToPost];
    NSLog(@"%@",logString);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:20.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSLog(@"All header Sent are %@", request.allHTTPHeaderFields);
   [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:ourBlock] resume];
```

Below is the console log for

> NSLog(@"All header Sent are %@", request.allHTTPHeaderFields);

```
All header Sent are {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    "postman-token" = "eb834958-a82f-3fd8-0b64-e007df45835c";
}
2016-12-21 10:36:07.091 MyAPP[7521:1256842] Here the Url With action is : 



  https://www.xyzz.com/app/xyz/dummy.php 




 and the Parmeter posted are :=============>
 &platform=ios&app_type=MyAPP&app_flag=18&version=1.3&account_type=1&user_type=1&device_id=xx
2016-12-21 10:36:08.324 MyAPP[7521:1256842] Response is <pre>Array
(
    [User-Agent] => MyAPP/1 CFNetwork/758.5.3 Darwin/15.6.0
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
    [Cache-Control] => no-cache
    [Accept-Language] => en-us
    [Connection] => close
    [Content-Length] => 151
    [Accept] => */*
    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [Postman-Token] => eb834958-a82f-3fd8-0b64-e007df45835c
    [Host] => www.xyz.com
)
```

I am sending  Connection = "keep-alive"; but im getting the response where the header received is print as close.

How can this be fixed .Any help is much appericated

Comment: This is not an iOS problem, because your server decides to close the connection.

Comment: Exactly.  Keep-alive is a handshake.  Your app requests it, and the server either accepts or rejects it.  If the server refuses to keep the connection alive, there's nothing that the client or the client OS can do about it.